# Run method after progress bar reaches 100%

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm using below code to call `writecsv()` method.

```
if (read_success == true && global_variables.csvtext == "not found")
               {

                   writecsv(null, null);

               }
```

What I want to do is, I need to show a progress bar on the windows form and once it reaches 100% (in around 4 seconds) i want to call `writecsv()` method.

Below is the code I used for the progress bar.

```
csvprogressbar.Maximum = 10000;
                   csvprogressbar.Step = 1;
                   csvprogressbar.Value = 0;
                   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                   {
                       csvprogressbar.Value = i;
                   }
```

I searched through the Internet but could not find a clear code.

I'm fairly new to programming with C# so I'd really appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Cheers.

Comment: Please post the code where you increase the value of the progress bar

Comment: Still don't see the code where you are increasing the value of the progress bar. You might be thinking about this the wrong way. Whatever is setting your progress bar to 100 could also be responsible for calling `writecsv` but we don't see your code so...

Comment: Below is the one I used. But can't figure out how to make the method run after the progress bar reaches 100%

  `csvprogressbar.Maximum = 10000;
                   csvprogressbar.Step = 1;
                   csvprogressbar.Value = 0;
                   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                   {
                       csvprogressbar.Value = i;
                   }`

Comment: Put that in your original question instead of the comments :)

Comment: It looks like you just need to add code in the foreach loop. `if (i == csvprogressbar.Maximum) { writecsv(null, null); }` I can't imagine that's your actual code, but whatever

Comment: Is there any work being done *during* the progress?

Comment: No work being done during the progress. It's just for presentation and to wait for like 4 seconds before the mothod runs.

Comment: This is weird. Did putting the code in the loop work or no?

Comment: Have a look at your code: when the for loop has finished your progress bar will inevitably be at 100%. So then you can call your method...

Answer (score 0):

OK here's the code I used. It's working fine now.

It will be called by `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++ )
            {
                simulateHeavyWork();
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            csvprogressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            writecsv(null, null);
        }
        private void simulateHeavyWork() 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(40);
        }
```